# Jquery: How to animate two set of numbers with different duration without repeating code?

Tags: jquery

My goal is to animate two set of numbers with different duration values without repeating code. How can I achieve this? Jquery:

```
  $('.counter').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function () {
  $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
   }
  });      
});
```

And the HTML:

```
    <div class="counter"><p>2017</p></div>

    <div class="counter"><p>1971</p></div>
```

I can achieve this by changing tha class name of the number "1971", but then i'll have repeated code...Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried writing your function with parameters?

Comment: well, no, i'm new at this :)

Comment: works fine, thanks for explanation cale_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the code you have, put it in a function that accepts arguments.

In the case below, I made the function accept an `sel` (css selector), and a `duration` value.  You could also add other values as you see fit.

To keep things simple, I also added classes to your html so that we can address each one separately.

```js
// Call the animation on the first item with a 1 second duration
animateNumber('.first-counter', 1000);
// Call the animation on the second item with a 5 second duration
animateNumber('.second-counter', 5000);

/**
 * Animate a numeric increment
 * 
 * @param {string} sel - the CSS selector of the element to animate
 * @param {int} duration - the number of milliseconds
 */
function animateNumber(sel, duration) {
    $(sel).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      jQuery({
        Counter: 0
      }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
      }, {
        duration: duration,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter first-counter">
  <p>2017</p>
</div>

<div class="counter second-counter">
  <p>1971</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another slightly different solution is assigning data-tags to your counters and controlling your timing that way.

```
<div class="counter" data-time="3000"><p>1971</p></div>

<div class="counter" data-time="4000"><p>2017</p></div>
```

---

Then within your existing function replacing the duration value with a call to the data-tag values.

```
$('.counter').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var duration = $(this).data('time');

  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: duration,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });      
});
```

[Here is a working example for you](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKwwrj).